# How to implement displaying different language captions in React Native?

Tags: react-native, caption

I need to display different captions (according to user selected "language") in a mobile app written in react native.

I want to implement them as arrays, for example, the captions for warning/page/message for
English / Spanish / Portuguest can be:

```
swarning: ["warning", "advertencia" , "Atenção"]
spage: ["page", "página" , "página"]
smessage: ["message", "mensaje" , "mensagem"]
```

Since I may use the captions more than once (I mean one caption can appear in different screens), what will be the best way to implement it in react native ?

Answer (score 1):

Please create a file say "global.js", as follows:

```
module.exports = {
swarning: ["warning", "advertencia" , "Atenção"],
spage: ["page", "página" , "página"],
smessage: ["message", "mensaje" , "mensagem"],
...... and so on
};
```

and then in your project screens, include this file:

```
GLOBAL = require('./globals');
```

After that, you may set a "language" state, say "0" as English, "1" as Spanish ad "2" as Portuguese to render the captions, such as

```
<View>
<Text>{GLOBAL.swarning[this.state.language]}</Text>

</View>
```